# Quick way to move an object some distance from one external vertex to another external vertex?

Tags: modeling, snapping

I'm trying to move away from Autodesk Max, but I work with a lot of 2d plans, and one thing that I do very very often is to move an object ( or vertices of one object ) a distance x, taking as reference two vertices of another object ( or different objects ).

I know that I can do this in Blender using the 3d cursor, but there's three steps involved, and as I said I do this a few hundred times per day. Is there any way ( even if it's an addon ) to do it faster, without middle steps, like in this animation ( from 3dsmax ):

[image: external snapping]

Comment: Have a look at [CAD transform](https://gumroad.com/l/nqvcs), and see if you get on with it. Personally, I think it looks very promising, but could do with a bit more feedback in use, to be really polished. I agree, Blender's Snap could be slicker and quicker.

Comment: I was checking this video ( https://youtu.be/TWEoZghkalc ) and it seems that CAD Transform addon is exactly what I was looking for. I'll give it a try and see if it suits my work pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They finally added this on Blender 3.5

Now you just need to grab <kbd>g</kbd> the object to move, then press <kbd>b</kbd> and select the origin vertex and finally just click the destination vertext.

[image]

( if you want to change the snapping method in the middle just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the update! :)

Answer (score 9):

A basic script for doing nearly the same (in object mode):

[image]

It is visually different as the object will move at first step then at the second one.

But the result is as expected, I think.

Use <kbd>D</kbd> key to use it. You can use Blender snapping options (i.e. snap to vertex) or not.

The principle is to use grab operator with invoke default from a modal operator:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

class GrabOffset(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Move an object by an offset"""
    bl_idname = "object.grab_offset"
    bl_label = "Grab with offset"

    def modal(self, context, event):

        #Left click
        if event.type in {'LEFTMOUSE'}:
            #Second left click?
            if self.second_locations:
                #Calculate delta and move objects
                for obj, floc, sloc in zip(context.selected_objects, self.first_locations, self.second_locations):
                    obj.location = floc + obj.location - sloc
                return {'FINISHED'}
            #First left click
            else:
                #Keep locations
                self.second_locations = [Vector(o.location) for o in context.selected_objects]
                bpy.ops.transform.translate('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

        #Aborting
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            context.object.location = self.first_location
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.selected_objects:
            #Keep original locations
            self.first_locations = [Vector(o.location) for o in context.selected_objects]
            self.second_locations = None

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            
            #Invoke grab
            bpy.ops.transform.translate('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
            
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "No active object, could not finish")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

keymaps = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(GrabOffset)
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new(GrabOffset.bl_idname, 'D', 'PRESS', shift=False)
        keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def unregister():
    for km, kmi in keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    keymaps.clear()
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GrabOffset)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    #bpy.ops.object.modal_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Was this oven-ready?

Comment: @RobinBetts, yes it is in the cook book.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe there's a cleaner way to do it but you could select all the objects, switch to *Edit* mode, enable the vertex snapping option (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to choose the vertex option), select these 5 vertices and duplicate:

[image]

Comment: The problem with this solution as you said is that is not very clean and if the object has a lot of geometry is kind of slow to work this way. Maybe someone can find a quicker and cleaner way like the one on the gif.

Comment: Well... I think it's cunning :D

Comment: @Robin, I think you've got the right way to do it, I always come with the most trashy ah ah, that said Fabman didn't want to use the 3D cursor, I don't know if it's avoidable though

Comment: It's pretty cunning indeed. I don't mind using the 3d cursor. It's pretty useful for plenty of cases, but in this case a simple one step movement has to be done in three or four steps. :-(

Comment: I wouldn't mind if it were something that you do once a day, but in this case I have to use hundreds of times while I'm working with plans.

Comment: Well you've got to have _some_ source ref. point... The plug-in 'CAD Transform' does that with a click, but still, you have to be in it, modally, and atm, I find it doesn't have the feedback to avoid confusion in use, IMO.

Answer (score 6):

In Blender the 'Snap With' > *Center* refers to the transform center in play at the time the snap is invoked. If *Transform Pivot Point* is set to '3D Cursor',  then, with Snap set to *With*: 'Center' and *To*: 'Vertex', for an  Object Mode snap, the steps are:

- Place the cursor at the source reference point. This could be done with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to the appropriate selected vertex in Edit mode, or, in Object mode, dragging and snapping the cursor itself, using the *Cursor* tool. If the *Cursor* tool's default shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, is too awkward for frequent use, you can change it, and/or add it to your Quick Menu.
- Drag the object, hovering over the desired target point.

[image]

(A duplicate used, here, for illustration.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, although this is what I was trying to avoid, having to use middle steps on the process.